Angular apply CSS to ::ng-deep elements conditionally
I've an component with template
HTML
<mt-select type="multi" hideSelected="true" [ngClass]="test ? 'bgblue' : 'bgGreen'"  [readonly]="!isProdUser" appendTo="body" [options]="searchResponse" openTagsOnHover [(ngModel)]="userSelection"   minLength="2" [viewFields]="['label']" uid="label" (search)="onUserSearch($event)">
</mt-select>

now there's one variable test in TS file which we either get true or false. So based on this variable value I need to apply some background color. By the way I'm using SCSS css preprocessor.
But I need to apply the css to the class mentioned in the image which is kind of hidden and can only be accessed using ::ng-deep.
I'm not sure how do I apply style to the hidden element with class lmn-select-input based on the variable value test.

i got the solution from here. Thanks link

Mostly, you have one way of doing that:

Create 2 CSS classes with needed background colors and don't forget to wrap them into the :host selector, because ng-deep styles are set globally and can affect other components and elements in HTML.

So, you will get:
:host::ng-deep {
  .primary-background {
    .some-deep-element-class-to-rewrite {
      background-color: blue;
    }
  }

  .secondary-background {
    .some-deep-element-class-to-rewrite {
      background-color: green;
    }
  }
}


Then you can set these 2 wrapper classes according to the needed condition (use [ngClass] or [class]):

<mt-select [class]="test ? 'primary-background' : 'secondary-background'"></mt-select>


I don't agree this is the only option. There are actually at least three ways to change your style:

::ng-deep. ng-deep disables viewEncapsulation for that particular selector so it's wise to combine it with :host as Yevhen mentioned (:host::ng-deep).

(not recommended!) Disabling component's viewEncapsulation:
@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})


You can also simply override the class in the global.scss file with higher specificity. for example if your element has 3 classes:
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content, .ui-state-default

then your selector should have higher specificity:
.ui-state-default .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default .hasSomeClass {
    color: red;
}

You can check what classes your element, and it's children/parents have in the browser inspector.


I'd recommend only using 1st and 3rd options, unless you know exactly what you are doing.
Some libraries allow you to override their css with custom properties and other methods to customize those elements so always check the docs first :)
